# Trying to get a variable from a function using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying to get the printed output into a variable. Whenever I call the function it just simply repeats the button process. I tried to utilize global, but it doesn't seem to work.

Help pls thanks.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk

def openFile():
    filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open for me")
    print(filepath)
    window.destroy()

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Insert Excel File")
window.geometry("200x200")
button = Button(text="Open",command=openFile,height=3,width=10)
button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It worked for me. Nothing wrong with the oode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print` , outputs the string to `stdout` it does not store the value in a variable, you'll need to store it yourself.

Since you're using a callback you can't return the value. The best way to implement this is to use classes, the bad way is to use a global variable to store the result

I'm assuming you are not familiar with classes, so a possible solution would be

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk

path = ""
def openFile():
    global path
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open for me")
    window.destroy()

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Insert Excel File")
window.geometry("200x200")
button = Button(text="Open",command=openFile,height=3,width=10)
button.pack()
window.mainloop()

# do something with path e.g. print
print(path)
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible you can show me the way with classes?

Comment: I won't show you straight away. If you want to learn about classes [this](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) is a good hands-on tutorial to begin with. Then try [this](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Introduction_to_GUI_Programming.html) to learn how the same concepts are applied in Tkinter. Then if you are still stuck, ask a new question. Good luck